# How can I force a newline in a layout grid if an element's text content is too long?

Tags: html, css, display

We are printing medical reports with xml/xslt/css and pdfreactor. Therefore we need exact positions in units.

The report is a table and some headers should be repeated on each page (colored red).
In table row 2 (=Analysis2) the field in column **Result** is too long to fit the column and I would like to have a new line with css (or javascript?) like in table row 3 (Analysis3, I prepared this row so that it looks like my expectation). Results are too important in a medical report and should not be wrapped.
Borders are not relevant.

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: a4;
    margin: 1cm;
    margin-top: 4cm;
    margin-bottom: 8cm;
  }
}

body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.PatientBox, .ResultBox, .AnalysisGroup {
  display:table;
/*   border-style: solid;  */
}

.PatientBoxHeader, .ResultBoxHeader, .AnalysisGruppeHeader {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
/*   border-style: solid; */
}

.Analysis, .Result, .ReferenceRange {
  float: left;
}
.Result{ position: absolute; left: 6.2cm;}  
.ReferenceRange { position: absolute; left: 10cm; } 


.ResultLine {
  display: table;
 } 
  
.ResultAnalysis, .Value, .ResultUnit, .Reference {
  display: table-cell;
  border-width: 0.01mm;
  border-style: solid;
/*   word-wrap: break-word; */
}

.ResultAnalysis { min-width: 6.2cm; max-width: 6.2cm; }
.Value { min-width: 1.8cm; max-width: 1.8cm; }
.ResultUnit { min-width: 1.8cm; max-width: 1.8cm; }
.Reference { min-width: 2.5cm; max-width: 2.5cm; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test6.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="PatientBox">                        <!-- Table -->
  <div class="PatientBoxHeader">Patient John Doe</div>      <!-- TableGroup -->

  <div class="ResultBox">                           <!--  Table  -->
    <div class="ResultBoxHeader">                       <!-- TableGroup -->
        <div class="Analysis">Analysis</div>
        <div class="Result">Result</div>
        <div class="ReferenceRange">Reference Range</div>
    </div>
    <div class="AnalysisGroup">                              <!--  Table  -->
      <div class="AnalysisGruppeHeader">Title1                  <!-- TableGroup -->
      </div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis1
          </div>
          <div class="Value">1000</div>
          <div class="ResultUnit">very lang ResultUnit xxxx</div>
          <div class="Reference">1-10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Comment">Comment</div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis2 veeeery veeeeery veeeery very long
          </div>
          <div class="Value">1000000000000</div>
          <div class="ResultUnit">mg/l</div>
          <div class="Reference">1-10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Comment">Comment</div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis3 
          </div>
          <div class="Value">1000000000000</div>
          <div class="ResultUnit"></div>
          <div class="Reference"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">
          </div>
          <div class="Value"></div>
          <div class="ResultUnit">mg/l</div>
          <div class="Reference">1-10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Comment">Comment</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That isn't a table. Why are you not using one? It might simplify things.

Comment: I'm actually confused about the request. The sentence beginning with "Analysis2" wraps nicely, and the next one isn't log enough to wrap anyway. What's the problem?

Comment: I agree with @isherwood this is tabular data that you're turning into a table with CSS when you could use an actual `table` with `tr` and `td` and nothing would be able to break out of it.

Comment: Wait, are you asking how to drop the value in one cell to the next line if the value in the previous cell overflows into it? Das ist ein bisschen seltsam.

Comment: I refer to the column with the heading Result where the value is = 100000000000000. The corresponding analysis is "Analysis2.....".
The lines with Analysis3 are an example as I would like should be.
CSS (or Javascript?) should start a new line after the result 1000000000000. Is such a thing possible at all?

Comment: the borders are not relevant

Comment: You haven't addressed my first question. If you used a table your column widths would flow more appropriately. Is that an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: a4;
    margin: 1cm;
    margin-top: 4cm;
    margin-bottom: 8cm;
  }
}

body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
}

.PatientBox, .ResultBox, .AnalysisGroup {
  display:table;
}

.ResultBoxHeader .Analysis,
.ResultBoxHeader .Result, 
.ResultBoxHeader .ReferenceRange {
  float: left;
  color: green;
}
.ResultBoxHeader .Result{ position: absolute; left: 6.2cm;}  
.ResultBoxHeader .ReferenceRange { position: absolute; left: 10cm; } 

.PatientBoxHeader, .ResultBoxHeader, .AnalysisGruppeHeader {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
  border-style: solid;
}

.AnalysenBox {
  clear: left;
}

.ResultLine {
  display: table;
 } 
 
  
.ResultLine .ResultAnalysis, 
.ResultLine .ResultBox,
.ResultLine .ResultReference {
  display: table-cell;
  border-width: 0.01mm;
/*   border-style: solid; */
  color: blue;
}

.Result { 
  display: block;
}

.ResultValue, .ResultUnit { 
  display: inline-block;
}

.ResultUnit { 
  float: right;
}

.ResultAnalysis, .ResultUnit, .ResultReference 
{ 
  word-wrap: break-word;
}

.ResultAnalysis { min-width: 6.2cm; max-width: 6.2cm; }
.ResultLine .ResultBox  { min-width: 3.8cm; max-width: 3.8cm;  } 
.ResultValue { min-width: 1.8cm; max-width: 3.8cm; }
.ResultUnit { min-width: 2cm; max-width: 2cm; }
.Reference { min-width: 2.5cm; max-width: 2.5cm; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test7.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="PatientBox">                        <!-- Table -->
  <div class="PatientBoxHeader">Patient</div>      <!-- TableGroup -->

  <div class="ResultBox">                           <!--  Table  -->
    <div class="ResultBoxHeader">                       <!-- TableGroup -->
        <div class="Analysis">Analysis</div>
        <div class="Result">Result</div>
        <div class="ReferenceRange">Reference Range</div>
    </div>
    <div class="AnalysenBox">
      <div class="AnalysisGroup">                              <!--  Table  -->
        <div class="AnalysisGruppeHeader">                    <!-- TableGroup -->
          <div class="Title">Title1</div>
        </div>
        <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis1</div>
          <div class="ResultBox">
            <div class="Result">
             <div class="ResultValue">1000</div>
             <div class="ResultUnit">very lang ResultUnit xxxx</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ResultReference">1-10</div>
        </div>
        <div class="Comment">Comment dhsgdahdhagjsdhas dgashadgahsdg adghsgadhgad adgahdgahdsgahgdhasgd</div>
        <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis2</div>
          <div class="ResultBox">
            <div class="Result">
             <div class="ResultValue">10000000000</div>
             <div class="ResultUnit">very lang ResultUnit xxxx</div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="ResultReference">1-10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using real tables too, but you can use `word-break: break-all;` in your css.

I put it in the body as example, but I wouldn't recommend that since it breaks words on any place.

```css
@media print {
  @page {
    size: a4;
    margin: 1cm;
    margin-top: 4cm;
    margin-bottom: 8cm;
  }
}

body
{
margin:0;
padding:0;
word-break: break-all;
}

.PatientBox, .ResultBox, .AnalysisGroup {
  display:table;
/*   border-style: solid;  */
}

.PatientBoxHeader, .ResultBoxHeader, .AnalysisGruppeHeader {
  display: table-header-group;
  font-weight: bold;
  color: red;
/*   border-style: solid; */
}

.Analysis, .Result, .ReferenceRange {
  float: left;
}
.Result{ position: absolute; left: 6.2cm;}  
.ReferenceRange { position: absolute; left: 10cm; } 


.ResultLine {
  display: table;
 } 
  
.ResultAnalysis, .Value, .ResultUnit, .Reference {
  display: table-cell;
  border-width: 0.01mm;
  border-style: solid;
/*   word-wrap: break-word; */
}

.ResultAnalysis { min-width: 6.2cm; max-width: 6.2cm; }
.Value { min-width: 1.8cm; max-width: 1.8cm; }
.ResultUnit { min-width: 1.8cm; max-width: 1.8cm; }
.Reference { min-width: 2.5cm; max-width: 2.5cm; }
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="test6.css" type="text/css" />
</head>
<body>

<div class="PatientBox">                        <!-- Table -->
  <div class="PatientBoxHeader">Patient John Doe</div>      <!-- TableGroup -->

  <div class="ResultBox">                           <!--  Table  -->
    <div class="ResultBoxHeader">                       <!-- TableGroup -->
        <div class="Analysis">Analysis</div>
        <div class="Result">Result</div>
        <div class="ReferenceRange">Reference Range</div>
    </div>
    <div class="AnalysisGroup">                              <!--  Table  -->
      <div class="AnalysisGruppeHeader">Title1                  <!-- TableGroup -->
      </div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis1
          </div>
          <div class="Value">1000</div>
          <div class="ResultUnit">very lang ResultUnit xxxx</div>
          <div class="Reference">1-10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Comment">Comment</div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis2 veeeery veeeeery veeeery very long
          </div>
          <div class="Value">1000000000000</div>
          <div class="ResultUnit">mg/l</div>
          <div class="Reference">1-10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Comment">Comment</div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis3 
          </div>
          <div class="Value">1000000000000</div>
          <div class="ResultUnit"></div>
          <div class="Reference"></div>
      </div>
      <div class="ResultLine">
          <div class="ResultAnalysis">
          </div>
          <div class="Value"></div>
          <div class="ResultUnit">mg/l</div>
          <div class="Reference">1-10</div>
      </div>
      <div class="Comment">Comment</div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm afraid that's not a solution, because results must not be wrapped in a medical report.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sample of what an actual table might look like.

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
}

table {
  width: 100%;
}

caption {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 18px;
}

th {
  background: #eee;
}

td {
  border: 1px solid #eee;
  padding: 5px;
  min-width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<table>
<caption>Patient John Doe</caption>
<thead>
<tr>
    <th>Analysis</th>
    <th colspan="2">Result</th>
    <th colspan="2" class="ReferenceRange">Reference Range</th>
</tr>

<tr>
    <th colspan="5" class="AnalysisGruppeHeader">Title 1</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr class="AnalysisGroup">
    <td class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis1</td>
    <td class="Value">1000</td>
    <td class="ResultUnit">mg/l</td>
    <td class="Reference">1-10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="Comment">Comment</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<thead>
<tr>
    <th colspan="5" class="AnalysisGruppeHeader">Title 2</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr class="AnalysisGroup">
    <td class="ResultAnalysis">Really long analysis 1 goes on for some time.</td>
    <td class="Value">10000000000000000000000</td>
    <td class="ResultUnit">mg/l</td>
    <td class="Reference">1-10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="Comment">Comment</td>
</tr>
</tbody>

<thead>
<tr>
    <th colspan="5" class="AnalysisGruppeHeader">Title 3</th>
</tr>
</thead>

<tbody>
<tr class="AnalysisGroup">
    <td class="ResultAnalysis">Analysis1</td>
    <td class="Value">1000</td>
    <td class="ResultUnit">mg/l</td>
    <td class="Reference">1-10</td>
</tr>

<tr>
    <td colspan="5" class="Comment">Comment</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```